# directive not producing template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('myGridTable',function($http){
     var tbl_tpl = '<table>';
     
     return {
         restrict:'AE',
          template:'{{tbl_tpl}}',
          replace:true,
          link:function(scope,element,attrib){
               $http.get(attrib.src).success(function(response) {
                    scope.rows = response.data;
                    //rows and columns population....
                    angular.forEach(scope.rows,function(value,key){
                         console.log(value);
                         tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "<tr>";
                         angular.forEach(value,function(val,k){
                              tbl_tpl=tbl_tpl + "<td>" + val + "</td>" ;
                         });
                         tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "</tr>";
                    });
                    tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "</table>";
                    scope.tbl_tpl=tbl_tpl;
               });             
          }
          
     };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

my query is that 'tbl_tpl' producing plain text if replace is off else showing error....hence do i have any way around of this problem

Comment: There should never be a reason to concat strings together when you are using AngularJS. Why not just use the `ngRepeat` directive and store the data returned as a JS array of objects?

Comment: You can't use `{{}}` for html...only text and as mentioned..just use `ng-repeat`

Comment: this was helpful :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest would be to just use a directive. No need to complicate with controllers etc.

Directive:

```
.directive('tableList', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<table><tr ng-repeat="row in rows"><td>{{row.property}}</td></tr></table>',
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            scope.rows = [];
            $http.get('/api/rows').then(function(response) {
                scope.rows = response.data;
            });             
        }
    };
});
```

And then use the directive in you template:

```
<table-list></table-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get rid of that string concatenation, add a controller and then bind a ngRepeat to the scope.rows and it will create some rows for you using whatever template you want

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myGridTableCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('myGridTable',function($http){     
  return {
     restrict:'AE',
      scope,
      link:function(scope,element,attrib){
           $http.get(attrib.src).success(function(response) {
                scope.rows = response.data;
           });             
      }

 };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<my-grid-table ng-controller="myGridTableCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
      {{row.property}}
    </div>
</my-grid-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('myGridTable',function($http){

     var tbl_tpl='';

     var linkFunc = function(scope,element,attrib){
          $http.get(attrib.src).success(function(response){
               scope.rows = response.data;
                tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "<thead>";
                    tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "<tr>";
                    angular.forEach(scope.rows[0],function(v,k){
                         tbl_tpl=tbl_tpl + "<th>" + k + "</th>" ;
                    });
                    tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "</tr>";
               tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "</thead>";

               tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "<tbody>";
               angular.forEach(scope.rows,function(value,key){
                    tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "<tr>";
                    angular.forEach(value,function(v,k){
                         tbl_tpl=tbl_tpl + "<td>" + v + "</td>" ;
                    });
                    tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "</tr>";
               });
               tbl_tpl = tbl_tpl + "</tbody>";

               element.html(tbl_tpl);
          });
     };


     return{
          restrict: 'AE',
          link: linkFunc
     };

});
```

after a little effort i was able to write the above code. and now my directive can produce a table with a provided json and with a dynamic template.